# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.util.Base64

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours and I haven't found a resource that resolves this issue. I've been following a video on YouTube to get S3 up and running. Looked through the GitHub repo as well and couldn't find anything that I was missing.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.486</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.util.Base64
    at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1620) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.163.jar:na]
    at com.tcc.managementSystem.aws.AmazonClient.uploadFile(AmazonClient.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tcc.managementSystem.controller.AWSController.uploadFile(AWSController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

Service

```
@Service
public class AmazonService {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @Value("${application.bucket.name}")
    private String bucketName;

    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile){

        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
        this.amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file));
        file.delete();
        return "File uploaded " + fileName;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        File convertedFile = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile)){
            fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertedFile;
    }
}
```

AWSConfig

```
@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 initializeAmazon(){
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                accessKey, secretKey);

        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region).build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there more to that stack trace?  It looks like that's just the first error.

Comment: Nope, that's all there was.

Comment: While the overhead with Spring is questionable, [here](https://springbootdev.com/2018/08/02/upload-and-delete-files-with-amazon-s3-and-spring-boot/) a V1 SDK example.

Comment: Amazon recommends moving to AWS SDK for Java V2

Comment: 1) You're not running the version of the SDK that you think you are: the stack trace reports `1.11.163`. I recommend using `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: 2) The important part is "Could not initialize class", not `NoClassDefFoundError`. The exception is (confusingly) used for any situation that prevents the JVM from loading a class. In this case, it appears to be the static initializer in `com.amazonaws.util.Base64`, which tries to figure out if the version of JAXB that's in use will cause problems.

Comment: That implies that the exception is caused by something else that you're not reporting. Perhaps you're using an older JVM as well, or one of the other dependencies pulls in an incompatible class.

Comment: Regardless, properly updating your SDK to a more recent vintage (it's currently at 1.11.900-something) may solve the problem.

Comment: I've updated my SDK to a newer version and it worked. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [@Parsifal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13400729/parsifal) in the comments.

I also encountered the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.util.Base64`

The underlying problem seems to be related to the JVM version.  On a windows jenkins build server, I also encountered the problem.

Original the server was running

```
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After updating to JVM to

```
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

the problem went away.